# Iterations of Pascal's Identity

Tags: combinatorics, applications, trees, combinatorial-game-theory

Pascal's Identity states that $n \choose k$ = $n-1 \choose k-1$ + $n-1 \choose k$ since if one element is separated from the rest we can claim that either it is chosen (resulting in $k-1$ elements left to choose from) or it is not (resulting in $k$ elements).  We can then take either of the two terms in the identity and apply the same reasoning so that it becomes $n \choose k$ = $n-2 \choose k-2$ + $n-2 \choose k-1$ + $n-1 \choose k$.  In general then the identity becomes something like:

$n \choose k$ = $\sum_s$$\sum_{k}$$n-s \choose k-s^{\lfloor k \rfloor}$

I am not quite sure how to expand this properly.  What would be the best way to write this expansion, and are there any interesting applications (maybe to binary trees) that comes from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$${n \choose k} = {n-1 \choose k-1} + {n-1 \choose k} = {n-1 \choose k-1}+{n-2 \choose k-1}+{n-2 \choose k} = ... =\sum_{i=k-1}^{n-1} {i \choose k-1}.$$
An application would be using this to compute $\sum\limits_{i=a}^b i^k$.
Or one can keep iterate the other term and get
$${n \choose k} = \sum_{i=0}^k {n-1-i \choose k-i}.$$
However, these two representations are the two sides of the same coin. Start from
$${n \choose k} = {n \choose n-k},$$
and apply the first expansion, we obtain
$${n \choose n-k}=\sum_{i=n-k-1}^{n-1} {i \choose n-k-1}=\sum_{i=0}^k {n-1-i \choose n-k-1}=\sum_{i=0}^k {n-1-i \choose k-i},$$
namely the second expansion.

Comment: Doesn't that exclude all the terms where we are choosing less than k-1 items?  As the terms continue to be split the 'denominator' will also be shrinking, won't it?  We'll eventually be choosing k-(k-1) = 1 terms.

Comment: The lower term does not shrink. Please observe the first two expansions closely. Every time you apply Pascal's identity the lower term always include one term involving $k-1$ and another keeping $k$. While it is true that the upper term keeps decreasing until it goes below $k$ which gives $0$ and thus terminates the series.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding Pascal's Identity then, but let me show my reasoning.  Consider $n-1 \choose k-1$.  This would equal $n-2 \choose k-2$ + $n-2 \choose k-1$.  Each time you are picking a new term to include or exclude from the subset, so the number of terms to pick from in the subset must decrease in at least one term per expansion.  The term $n-2 \choose k-2$ would when expanded include a term $n-3 \choose k-3$ and so on.

Comment: That is right too. Do you see the different terms we are each taking to iterate? One expression can have many representations. I just added this expansion in my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Yes, I realized after I had written the comment, that was my mistake.  I guess what I meant in my initial question is what happens if we take each term and expand it down to its smallest parts?  From what I understand now though that doesn't actually make sense, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: @user167176: To explicate the two representations further, I have edited my answer and shown both representations can be derived from the same expansions. Take a look.